# How can I mutate a column to returns a value if all observations of a certain level have the same value?

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, data-cleaning, summarization

I previously asked a question regarding how to create a column identifying rows with levels that consist only of new data in a data frame/tibble using the `dplyr` package in R ([How can I create a column identifying rows consisting only of new data in a summarized data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896842/how-can-i-create-a-column-identifying-rows-consisting-only-of-new-data-in-a-summ)). The answers there were very helpful, however, when I went to plot the data I found out there was an issue with the way I was going about the code. Specifically, in the raw data there are several rows in which there were errors in the reported data from the parent data set that I fixed by going back to the raw data recordings. To record these, I made new rows with the corrected data from the original data sheets and retained the old data with the identifier column `drop`.

The problem is that I set up a filter to drop the erroneous columns before I summarised the data, so when I try to create the `new` column using the `summarise` function observations for which the level species is *not* new but have no unaltered observations being used to create the summary values are returned as new, which makes the dataset seem like there a lot more completely new species being added to the data set than there really are.

Here is a short set of code that produces a reproducible example...

```
df<-data.frame(species = c("Species1","Species1","Species2","Species2","Species3","Species3","Species4","Species4"), new=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),
var=c(1,1,2,2,8,3,4,4),
drop=c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE))
df2<-df%>%
  filter(drop!=TRUE)%>%
  group_by(species)%>%
  summarise(var=mean(var))
```

What I want to produce is a dataset like the following.

```
data.frame(species=c("Species1","Species2","Species3","Species4"),
new=c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE"),
var=c(1,2,3,4))
```

I tried adding a `mutate` call before the `filter` call to try and produce such a column, as shown in the code below.

```
df2<-df%>%
  group_by(species)%>%
  mutate(new2=(all(new)==TRUE))%>%
  filter(drop!=TRUE)%>%
  group_by(species)%>%
  summarise(var=mean(var),new=all(new2))
```

However, the first `group_by` call function doesn't seem to work in this case and I get the same results as in the above code. **I am trying to figure out how to return a certain value for a column if all observations of that column have the same level**. I think if I can get that I can then use the solution in the previous question to produce the column for the summarized data frame.

I realize that this is a similar issue to my previous question, but because this is an issue with creating the column *without* using the `summarise` rather than how to select values within the `summarise` function and adding this new information would invalidate the answers to my previous question, I submitted it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(species) %>%
    mutate(new = all(new)) %>% 
    filter(!drop) %>%
    summarise(new = all(new), var = mean(var))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  species  new     var
#  <chr>    <lgl> <dbl>
#1 Species1 TRUE      1
#2 Species2 FALSE     2
#3 Species3 FALSE     3
#4 Species4 FALSE     4
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Adding it to the code produces the same result as the initial code. Additionally it looks like slice_tail just returns the value of the first row of whatever species group is selected. I don't think this would work on the actual dataset where there are more than two rows per group, in some cases where the first value of new isn't always false.

Comment: @user2352714 i get the same output as your expected except that you dropped the column 'drop'

Comment: When I ran it I still got the value new==TRUE for Species3. Additionally, there is still the issue that if the order of the rows were reversed and the observation where new==TRUE was first, slice_tail would return the value TRUE

Comment: The new code now returns the erroneous value of var==8 for species 3 that I was trying to filter out instead of the correct value of 3

Comment: @user2352714 you have two 'df2' in the post.  which one is the expected

Comment: The expected result is the one in the middle, the data.frame that is not stored as df2

Comment: @user2352714 anyway, the update gives the expected output as showed in your code

Comment: @user2352714 I don't understand why your last 'df2' is not working.  it seems to give the expected output as well.  I think that was the confusion